# Python 3.9 Download and Save HTML - File is garbled

Tags: html, python-3.x

I have a simple Python script that successfully retrieves a web page and saves the web page as an .html on my local pc. When I open the local .html file, regardless of URL/web site, the file contains garbage. This seems like an encoding problem or a binary-to-text problem but not sure how to fix it?

```
cache = scrape_cache_dir + 'cache_' + symbol + '_' + cachetime + '.html'

try:
    response = urlopen(URL_TARGET)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
    print(err.code)
html_doc = response.read()
fh = open(cache,'w')
fh.write(str(html_doc))
fh.close()
```

Here is a sampling of the resulting file that was saved

b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xec\xbd\xebv\xdbF\xb20\xfa\x7f\x9e\x02bb\x9b\xdc& \xdcy3\xed\x91%9\xf6\x8cd\xe9\x93\x94xg\xbc\xbd\xb9@\x00\x14\x11\x83\x00\x03\x80\xbaX\xe1\xb7\xcek\x9c\xd7;Or\xaa\xaa\x1b n\x94(Y\xcexf\xcd8#\x02\x8d\xbeVU\xd7\xa5\xbb\xab\xfa\xc5\xd6\xde\xd1\xee\xd9\xaf\xc7\xfb\xc24\x99\xf9/*\xe0*\xc1s\x86\r+\tg\x9e\xdd\x10l\xdf\x8a\xe3a\xe3}\xf8\xb7X\xb0\xa7Q8s\x05\xc7\x8d?'\xe1\\x98X\x9e\x1f[\x13\xb7!\xf8Vp>l\xb8\x81\xf8\xf3i\x03\xeap-G\x98G\xee\xc4\xbb\x1a6\xc2\xf3>T\x9d\xcc\xfb\xdb\xdb\xe1\xf9\\x9a\xb9\xdbA\xfc\x03d\x8a\xed\xc8\x9b'//\xbd\xc0\t/\xa5\xb9\x1bM\xc2hf\x05\xb6+

Comment: when I change response.read() to response.read().decode('utf-8') I get this error message "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python39\Scripts\batch_save_html.py", line 58, in <module>
    html_doc = response.read().decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte"

Comment: what does `print(html_doc)` give you right after `html_doc = response.read()`? Perhaps you need an `encoding="utf-8"` on your `open()`. I think `html_doc` is already a string so I don't think you need to recast it as such.

Comment: THANK YOU!  print(html_doc) right after html_doc = response.read() looks similar if not exactly the same as the character encoding I posted in the main message. Any additional thoughts are appreciated.